# Mamp apache server not starting

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp

I installed mamp for the first time recently and i tried setting up the apache server but it wouldn't start. I reinstalled mamp multiple times and changed ports multiple time but it won't start. How can i get it to work?

Comment: Well what errors are you getting

Comment: Doesn't the MAC come with Apache and PHP pre installed?